# How to have scatter points become larger for higher density using matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I am using matplotlib to draw a plot. The x and y axises are discrete values and therefore, several (x,y) points in the list have the same values. For example, assume we have the following x,y points:

```
x=[0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
y=[0,1,2,3,3,3,3,5]
```

Now all of the (x,y) points occur once, but (2,3) occurs 4 times. When I use *plt.scatter(x,y)*, it only shows (2,3) as a regular point, once. How is it possible to show the density of occurrence, too? For example, a bigger marker?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pass an optional argument `s` to `plt.scatter` that indicates the size of each point being plotted.  To get the size to correspond with the occurrences of each point, first construct a dictionary that count the occurrences, then create a list of the sizes for each point.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

x=[0,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
y=[0,1,2,3,3,3,3,5]

# count the occurrences of each point
c = Counter(zip(x,y))
# create a list of the sizes, here multiplied by 10 for scale
s = [10*c[(xx,yy)] for xx,yy in zip(x,y)]

# plot it
plt.scatter(x, y, s=s)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Better use `s = [10*c[(x1,y1)] for x1,y1 in zip(x,y)]` to avoid side effect to the original x, y.

Comment: For large data sets, this takes a while; is there a more efficient solution for this?

Answer (score 9):

Setting the transparency to be smaller than 1 could be one way to visualize this; A more frequent dot will appear darker/less transparent if *alpha* is smaller than 1:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=80, alpha=0.2)
```

[image]