# Multi Label Text Data Visualization

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn, multilabel-classification

I have multi-label text data. I want to visualize this data in python in some good graph to get an idea how much overlapping exist in my data and also wanted to know if there is any pattern exist in overlapping like when 40% of times class_1 is coming then also class_40 is coming too.

Data is in this form:

```
paragraph_1  class_1
paragraph_11 class_2
paragraph_1  class_2
paragraph_1  class_3
paragraph_13 class_3
```

What is the best way to visualize such data? Which library can help in this case seaborn, matplotlib etc?

Comment: what about a [heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from collections import Counter

x = ['paragraph1', 'paragraph1','paragraph1','paragraph1','paragraph2', 'paragraph2','paragraph3','paragraph1','paragraph4']
y = ['class1','class1','class1', 'class2','class3','class3', 'class1', 'class3','class4']


# count the occurrences of each point
c = Counter(zip(x,y))

# create a list of the sizes, here multiplied by 10 for scale
s = [10*c[(xx,yy)] for xx,yy in zip(x,y)]

plt.grid()
# plot it
plt.scatter(x, y, s=s)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The higher is the occurence, the bigger is the marker.

Different question, but  same answer proposed by @James can be found here: [How to have scatter points become larger for higher density using matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700733/how-to-have-scatter-points-become-larger-for-higher-density-using-matplotlib)

***Edit1 (if you have bigger dataset)
Different approach using heatmaps:***

```py
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

x = ['paragraph1', 'paragraph1','paragraph1','paragraph1','paragraph2', 'paragraph2','paragraph3','paragraph1','paragraph4']
y = ['class1','class1','class1', 'class2','class3','class3', 'class1', 'class3','class4']

# count the occurrences of each point
c = Counter(zip(x,y))

# fill pandas DataFrame with zeros
dff = pd.DataFrame(0,columns =np.unique(x) , index =np.unique(y))

# count occurencies and prepare data for heatmap
for k,v in c.items():
    dff[k[0]][k[1]] = v

sns.heatmap(dff,annot=True, fmt="d")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My data size for multi-label is half million. Will this still be helpful in that case?

Comment: I don't recommend approach with size of markers if you have big dataset. The only other solution which comes to my mind are heatmaps. I edited solution, so you can try it. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks again for the update. Its great but as size of my data is too big so this graph will become congested.